# Highcharts JS getting very slow when updating with many data points

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I have a static local webpage that is supposed to be updated with data from a csv file (so as data is written to the file, the page should update and display the new data). My issue is that with many data pointys, it becomes very slow and after a certain number of points it will not update at all.

Currently, the way that the page updates is that it reads the file every 3 seconds and updates accordingly. I imagine a much more efficient way would be to see what are the most recent additions to the file and then just append those new points to the current data set. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Code below parses the csv file and separates the data to arrays to be used in the charts:

```
function  parseCSVData(csvFile) {

    time = [];
    altitude = [];
    outsideTemp = [];
    insideTemp = [];
    voltage = [];
    state = [];
    velocity = [];
    degrees = [];
    // cut CSV dataFiles into lines
    var lines = csvFile.split("\n");

    $.each(lines, function (lineNumber, line) {

        if (lineNumber != 0) {   // skip header line
            var fields = line.split(",");


            var missionTime = parseInt(fields[1]);
            var altitude2 = parseInt(fields[2]);
            var outsideTemp2 = parseInt(fields[3]);
            var insideTemp2 = parseInt(fields[4]);
            var voltage2 = parseInt(fields[5]);
            var state2 = parseInt(fields[6]);
            var velocity2 = parseInt(fields[7]);
            var degrees2 = parseInt(fields[8]);

            time.push(missionTime);
            altitude.push(altitude2);
            outsideTemp.push(outsideTemp2);
            insideTemp.push(insideTemp2);
            voltage.push(voltage2);
            state.push(state2);
            velocity.push(velocity2);
            degrees.push(degrees2);

        }
    });
}
```

This is the code to update the charts every 3 seconds:

```
setInterval(function blah() {

    var file = fileName+'?q='+Math.random();
    fillCharts(file);//which calls the parseCSVData function and fills the charts
}, 3000);
```

EDIT: pastebin with entire code: http://pastebin.com/Qmzn8azY

EDIT2: sample csv data:

```
TEAM_ID,MISSION_TIME,ALT_SENSOR,OUTSIDE_TEMP,INSIDE_TEMP,VOLTAGE,FSW_STATE,VELOCITY,DEGREES
ubArtemis,0,36,20,20,9,1,0,0
ubArtemis,1,45,18,20,9,1,6,2
ubArtemis,2,200,16,20,9,1,10,5
ubArtemis,3,65,14,19,9,1,15,3
ubArtemis,4,79,12,17,8,2,22,4
ubArtemis,5,100,10,16,8,3,30,2
ubArtemis,6,120,8,15,8,4,39,0
```

Comment: What is in `fillCharts`? If you only do the parsing, is it slow then? I would assume there might be some `update` operation that could be optimized. At least that is a common problem-function.

Comment: In your real scenario, are you reading from a single file? And are changes to that file always appends of additional rows, or are the contents of existing rows altered?

Comment: @Ondkloss I added a pastebin link with my code. the fillCharts just initializes the 6 charts for the webpage. its like 200 lines long and very repetitive, so i didn't paste it originally

Comment: @SMcCrohan It is supposed to read from a single, defined csv file, and additional data is appended as lines

Comment: It looks like you are completely remaking all the charts for each update. This is massively overkill, and costly in performance. You should find some way to update only the new/changed data. I'm not sure what changed you can expect in your CSV, but you might need `Chart.addSeries`, `Series.addPoint`, `Series.setData`, `Series.update`...